# Entity Framework version 6 using in ASP.NET Core 6.0 not creating the Database in the SQL Server after Add-Migration command

Tags: asp.net-core

The database is not getting created after Add-migration command when using ASP.Net Core 6.0 web application.

Connection string given below (i am using local db for testing/learning purpose)

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\local; Database=PradeepShopping; Trusted_Connection=True"
  }
```

The database is not getting created.

Comment: any logs, errors or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to do another step.

After "add-migration", you have to call "update-database"

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `view` -> `terminal` in Visual Studio.
2. Type `cd ./{your projectname with migrations}`.
3. Run `dotnet ef database update`.

Done.

p.s.

To rollback database or apply specify migration use:
`dotnet ef database update {migration name}`